# React build fails everytime with uglify error

Tags: reactjs, npm, uglifyjs

I started a project using 'create-react-app' command and when I do npm run command the command is successfully run but when I use npm build command it fails with the following error everytime.

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js run build --scripts-prepend-node-path=auto

> finteen-web@0.1.0 build /home/jayg/Documents/MyCode/Code/Web/finteen-web
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/js/main.626dbb4b.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (length) [/home/jayg/~/punycode/punycode.js:55,0]

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! finteen-web@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the finteen-web@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jayg/.npm/_logs/2019-12-13T17_52_13_422Z-debug.log

Process finished with exit code 1
```

With create-react-app version:0.9.5

Comment: Do mention the version of create-react-app and nodejs and npm you are using. It builds fine with the latest build from github for me. Also the logfile would be helpful `/home/jayg/.npm/_logs/2019-12-13T17_52_13_422Z-debug.log`

Comment: updating the create-react-app version worked

Answer (score 1):

Update your create-react-app version following the [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) of create react app